# Scala paging iterating over legacy java method until condition is met

Tags: scala

In a Scala code, I need to loop over a legacy paginated Java endpoint until no more calls are required.

Naive pseudo solution -

```
var data: Seq[Data]

while(data.length < 1000) 
    // paging.limit is 1000
    // getData return List[Data]
    var newData = getData(paging.offset, paging.limit).asScala
    data = data ++ newData
```

What is the more Scala way to do it?

Comment: What type does `getData` return?

Comment: Added the return type

Comment: You may use `unfold`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I did:

`Stream.from(0, 1000).map(offset => getData(offset, 1000)).takeWhile(listSize => listSize.size() == 1000).flatten`

WDYT?

Comment: @Johnny yeah if you are trapped in `2.12` with no `unfold` then that feels like a good alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do a task for indefinite times is to use `LazyList`:

```scala
// This generates a list of unknown number of elements (less than 10)
def getData(pageNumber: Int): List[Int] = 
  List.fill(scala.util.Random.between(1,10))(scala.util.Random.between(1,100))
    
LazyList
  .from(0)    // Create infinite LazyList and track the page number
  .map(getData)
  .flatten    //flatten is needed because getData generates a list. You can combine with map and use flatMap. 
              //If it generates single element, then it is not needed.
  .take(1000) //Take number of element from this LazyList. It will not go over that because it is lazy
  .toList     // Materialize this LazyList
```

**EDIT**

For Scala 2.12 and older, use Stream.